# Why does this element partially disappear when I do display:none on another element?

Tags: html, css

Why does the phone number disappear in Image 2 when I use a display:none property in the ul.languages CSS below?  here is a link to the JS fiddle where altering the CSS as described below gives the same effect: https://jsfiddle.net/bpjavascript/31z5t24u/

I didn't setup the original CSS/html, but it seems as if in this case the 2 block level elements "" and "" wouldn't affect each other this way.

**Image 1 - Phone number displays correctly with the languages block**

[image]

**Image 2 - phone disappears and goes off screen**

[image]

**If I add "display:none" in the below CSS, the phone number disappears partially as in Image 2**

```
header.branding section.scctsi ul.languages {
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      top: 5px; 
       }
```

Comment: Without seeing the CSS/HTML for the other elements it's hard to say for sure, but you may need to confirm your floated elements are being cleared in the CSS

Answer (score 1):

The css you are using is overly complicated and specific it is not partially hidden it is just covered by this class

```
header.branding section.scctsi:before, header.branding section.scctsi:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
background: #fff;
/* Match the background */
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 9999px;
/* some huge width */ }
```

If you also add a display: none; property to that class the phone number will be visible again.